# Have to and Have got to

Tags: american-english, british-english, have-got

Do the Britons (British people) say both?

And, I've found it from the book that said:

"Have got to" is more informal than "have to", so do Britons say this:

1. I have to get a great score than last exam. (AE/BrE) is this common in BrE?
2. I have got to get a great score than last exam. (BrE) is usually used in speaking.
3. I gotta get a great score than last exam. (Informal AE).

So, the question is which is more preferred in BrE, in spoken and written BrE?

Comment: In terms of your question both of the first two are widely used in BrE. Even the third one is sometimes used informally, although the pronunciation is slightly different from the American. In many parts of society you will also hear 'gorra' where Americans would say 'gotta'. However the rest of your example sentence is very wrong. The word 'than' indicates a comparison so 'great' should be 'greater' but even that is not really idiomatic. An example of a sentence meaning what I think you intend to say would be "I've got to get a better score than I did in the last exam"

Comment: And all three are widely used in AmE, as well, although *"I have got to"* is viewed as much less formal than *"I have to"* here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes we do use the term "I have to" when talking generally. 
we also use "I have got to" when speaking more formally at interviews or even writing.
"i Gotta" is not good English but is used regularly throughout England verbally.

also to correct your sentence it is either:
1.I have to get a great score.
2.I have to get a great(er) score than last time.

hope this helps

Comment: On the contrary, "I have got to" is the informal version.